# sqlite3 database not found when looked for in file explorer

Tags: database, sqlite, file

why isn't this database stored in the folder where the sqlite3.exe file is?

I don't know what I can try to solve this.

https://gyazo.com/44648db7a1d866af821c378fb1e4d933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, had to open with administrator rights, should've known that